# Passing variables in a querystring

Tags: php, email

i want to pass $Email in a querystring, which looks like this

```
header("Location:index.php?state=sent&Email=$Email");
$Email = urlencode("$urlencode");
$urlencode = $row['Email'];
```

I have defined $row earlier on, from my database

and this shall recieve it

```
$Email = $_GET['Email'];
echo "<p style='color:white;margin-bottom:10%; font-size:17px;' align='center'> Your email is: $Email</p>";
```

But for some reason it will not send the Email with the querystring

Comment: Your code is backwards. I don't even know how one manages something like this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got the order wrong.
should be:

```
$urlencode = $row['Email'];
$Email = urlencode($urlencode);
header("Location:index.php?state=sent&Email=$Email");
```

Comment: Oh, thanks.
I just remembered i've read somewhere that Header always have to be in the very top for it to work

Comment: @JapSeyz, the thing you are mis-remembering is that `header` and other things that emit headers (like `setcookie`) have to be placed before non-header output, like `echo`s and `print`s.